# Jenkins Pipeline - remoteTriggerJob is always returning status as Queued though the remote job in running & finished

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am using the below code to trigger another job in another [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) instance using pipeline.

```
def handle = triggerRemoteJob(
                        abortTriggeredJob: true,
                        enhancedLogging: true,
                        job: 'xxx',
                        maxConn: 1,
                        parameters: 'Ear_Version=1.0.0',
                        pollInterval: 10,
                        remoteJenkinsName: 'another@jenkins.com',
                        token: 'xcxcx',
                        useCrumbCache: true,
                        useJobInfoCache: true,
                        blockBuildUntilComplete: false
                        )
                        def status = handle.getBuildStatus().toString();
                        while(!handle.isFinished()) {
                           echo 'Current Status: ' + handle.getBuildStatus().toString();
                           sleep 5
                        }
```

Status inside *while* loop is always QUEUED. I am not sure what I am missing here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
blockBuildUntilComplete: true
shouldNotFailBuild: true
```

You should set these parameter values as true, after that you should get the status properly. Give a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `handle.updateBuildStatus()`

You can refer to the sample code listed in https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/README_PipelineConfiguration.md#user-content-nonblocking

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33462988)